# Alchemy says I have no rebis, but inventory does

Tags: the-witcher-2

In *The Witcher 2*, I’m trying to brew Petri’s Philter and it is telling me I have no rebis. But I have 44 Celandine in my inventory which says it contains rebis.

Why can’t I brew the potion? Why does it say it is missing?

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]